# How to access Controller Service created in UI into Root processors in NiFi-1.1.1?

Tags: apache-nifi

In nifi-1.1.0 i have created controller services like below.,
[image]

After creating Controller services i have drag and drop the putSQL in UI.

[image]

In JDBC Connection Pool,it can show created controllerservice.

But in NiFi-1.1.1 i do same procedure but ConnectionPool doesn't shown.

**Nifi-1.1.1:**

1.i have created controller service like below.

[image]

2.Drag the PutSQL in Root canvas.It can't show already created service.
[image]

i don't know exactly is this correct behaviour for NiFi-1.1.1?

can anyone explain concepts behind controller service creation in Nifi-1.1.1 root canvas?

**EDIT-1:**

I haven't see the access policies in "Reporting Tasks".Look at below image.

[image]

But in your referral link i can see access policies in controller services tab.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Controller_Services_for_Reporting_Tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NiFi 1.x, any controller services created from the global menu in the top-right are only for use by reporting tasks.

If you want the controller service to be used by a processor, you need to create the controller service from the context palette on the left inside the corresponding process group (or on the root canvas).

See this documentation:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Controller_Services

Comment: ,Can you check my query in EDIT-1?

Comment: @MahendraPrabhu can you start a new question? the original question about how to access controller services has been answered, the question of how to apply access policies to reporting tasks is a different question